# Without allocating memory how am I able to create and assign values to variables?

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node* next;
};

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(0);
    cout.tie(0);

    node* temp;
    temp->data=5;
    temp->next=0;
    cout<<temp->data;

    return 0;
}
```

Without allocating memory in heap why is this code working? If it's correct why we allocate memory in heap to create nodes in linked lists?

Comment: This is undefined behavior.

Comment: It's not correct and I really doubt it's working

Comment: @tkausl what do you mean by undefined behavior

Comment: @BigTemp Its working fine and I also created another node and assigned its next to first pointer that's also working. I don't know why but it is true.

Comment: It means anything could happen.

Comment: @tkausl Ha ha  btw I am using codeblocks

Comment: Undefined behaviour will vary between compilers, it means anything could happen. Relying on such behaviour is bad practice. `temp` has no valid pointer so could be pointing at anything (aka any memory address).

Comment: [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). `temp` is not initialized and contains garbage value. It could have any valid or invalid memory address.

Comment: @Azeem But its giving correct value every time I run the program.

Comment: UPDATE: WHEN I AM TRYING TO OUTPUT TEMP ITS SHOWING ME 0. WHAT DOES IT MEAN

Comment: Please don't shout. We can't help you with undefined behaviour, you need to fix your code and then see if it's still broken. Assign a new instance of `node` to `temp`.

Comment: @cgDude Rudeness doesn't help here I'm afraid.

Comment: @AStopher bro I not being rude but I just want to clarify that I am still learning and it's crucial for me to have deep knowledge so that tomorrow it may not create bigger problems.

Comment: @cgDude: See the warnings with three different compilers: https://godbolt.org/z/np6wiz.

Comment: @cgDude: Welcome! Relevant read: [Uninitialized variables](https://en.cppreference.com/book/uninitialized).

Answer (score 1):

In C and C++ "undefined behaviour" means you did something really badly wrong, and *anything* can happen as a result. It can range from your program crashing, to your programming destroying what's on your hard drive, to nothing going wrong that you can see until you give your program to a customer, where it will destroy *their* hard drive. Don't ask "what does it mean". Just DON"T DO IT.

I suggest that you find out how to make your compiler warn for serious bugs for this one, and best to turn all warnings into errors. In my setup, that code wouldn't even compile. `temp->data` alone would give an error "access to an uninitialised variable temp".